# How to set up an APT repository?

Tags: apt, package-management, repository

I would like to set up an APT repository on a server that will provide a couple of packages.

Is there a way to set one up *without* installing any software on the server?

How do the files have to be organized?

---

**Edit:** I must be doing something wrong... can someone please help me? I have the repository at http://quickmediasolutions.com/apt/dists

I'm not sure where or what, but something's misconfigured. I only currently have one package and it's for all architectures.

Here's what's been added to my `/etc/apt/sources.list`:

```
deb http://quickmediasolutions.com/apt stable main
```

Comment: Can you edit and add what kind of license the applications you downloaded are in? Is this for private use or do you plan to distribute them, etc.?

Comment: @Jorge: What do you mean? What applications?

Comment: I was trying to determine if the package was OSS you could just use launchpad.

Comment: @Jorge: No, it isn't OSS. (In fact, it's pretty much the only app I've written that isn't.)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Setting up a trivial repository is very easy using dpkg-scanpackages. [This page](https://web.archive.org/web/20230503192430/https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/repository-howto/repository-howto#setting-up) explains how to set up a trivial repo, and [this one](https://web.archive.org/web/20230503192430/https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/repository-howto/repository-howto#using-a-repository) explains how to use it (scroll down to example 4).

Comment: Having a bit of trouble getting it to work. Please see my update to the question.

Comment: It looks like you're trying to set up an "automatic" repo. For one (or just several) package(s), you'll be much better off using a trivial repo. Try moving your Packages.gz and deb all the way up to http://quickmediasolutions.com/apt/binary. Then your source will be `deb http://quickmediasolutions.com/apt binary/`.

Comment: Trivial repos present problems when pinning, but yes, they are the quickest / easiest way to set up a repo for just a few packages. It would seem silly to set up a pooled repo just for 2 - 3 packages.

Comment: George, were you ever able to make this work?

Comment: @mac: Well.... I haven't had time to try it yet :) I ended up just uploading everything to a PPA.

Answer (score 41):

Just set up a **simple but signed repository** on a webserver. Because most other tutorials are somewhat dated or cumbersome, I'll try to replicate the procedure here. The initial configuration takes a bit of effort, but the simple build script keeps it easy to manage. And you can just drop in new `*.deb` files, then update, or let a cron job handle that.

#### Generate some signing keys

First you need to create a `gpg` signing key for packages and your repository. Make it a (4) RSA signing key, no password, and give it a unique `$KEYNAME` when asked for. (Further examples assume "`dpkg1`" as keyname.)

```
 gpg --gen-key
 gpg -a --export-secret-key dpkg1 > secret.gpg
 gpg -a --export dpkg1            > public.gpg
```

I said no password, because your webserver has no builtin monkey to type it in repeatedly. And the signed packages and repository are only meant to satisfy the update-managers complaints about that. Just upload both keys to the new `/apt/` repository directory on your webserver, but delete the `secret.gpg` key *after* initialization.

#### Update CGI script

This is the simple update shell/CGI script for it:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo Status: 200 Okay
echo Content-Type: text/plain
echo
echo Rebuilding APT repository:

{
  #-- settings
  export GNUPGHOME=/var/www/usr12345/files
  export KEYNAME=dpkg1
  #-- one-time setup
  if [ ! -e "$GNUPGHOME/secring.gpg" ] ; then
     gpg --import -v -v ./secret.gpg
     gpg --import -v -v ./public.gpg
     gpg --list-keys
  fi

  #-- symlink .deb files from adjacent sub-directories
  find .. -name '*.deb' -exec ln -s '{}' . \;

  #-- build Packages file
  apt-ftparchive packages . > Packages
  bzip2 -kf Packages

  #-- signed Release file
  apt-ftparchive release . > Release
  gpg --yes -abs -u $KEYNAME -o Release.gpg Release

} 2>&1
```

The three `gpg` lines only need to be executed once, to initialize the GPG setup in some directory `$GNUPGHOME` (above the document root). Delete only the `secret.gpg` after success.

One unique feature of this small shell script is that it accepts any `*.deb` files that you drop in, but also searches recursively (starting from one level up) for others, and symlinks them in. (Needs .htaccess `Options FollowSymLinks` eventually.)

You can either execute this script manually as CGI or per cron-job. But hide it, or better yet move it out of the document root.

Because it's a "trivial" apt repository it needs the following `apt-sources.list` entry:

```
deb http://example.org/deb/  ./    # Simple signed repo
```

That's suitable for single-architecture repositories, and if you don't expect hundreds of packages.

#### Package signing

Signing your individual packages is also trivial, once you've set up your gpg keys:

```
dpkg-sig -k dpkg1 -s builder *.deb
```

(This should be done on the workstation where packages are built, not on the repository webserver.)

#### Unsigned repository

If you don't need signed packages, then you could slash the update script down to just:

```
  dpkg-scanpackages . > Packages
  bzip2 -kf Packages
```

Which can still be used by average users, but needs a custom flag for `apt.sources`:

```
deb [trusted=yes] http://apt.example.org/deb/ ./
```

But please don't use the `trusted=yes` flag habitually for everything, or if you're not actually sure about the package origin.

#### For usability

For end users, just drop a `HEADER.html` into the repository directory. Apaches `mod_auto_index` will prepend that note:

```
<h1>http://example.org/apt/</h1>
<dl>
<dt>Add this repository to /etc/apt/sources.list as:
 <dd><kbd>deb http://example.org/apt/ ./  # example repo</kbd>
<dt>Import verification key with:
 <dd><kbd>wget -q http://http://example.org/apt/public.gpg -O- | sudo apt-key add -</kbd>
</dl>
```

#### Alternatives

There are a few tools to automate repository management these days. And there are even repository online hosters and package build services ([gemfury](https://gemfury.com/), [packagecloud](https://packagecloud.io/), [bintray](https://bintray.com/) etc.)

- A rather convenient alternative is [prm](https://rubygems.org/gems/prm). It's a Ruby script, which builds complex APT and YUM repos. (But let's just hope RPM finally dies out sometime soon..) - It's best installed per `gem install prm`.
- And I've also written a small script to automate this similarly: http://apt.include-once.org/apt-phparchive - Please not that it's not overly robust and written in PHP (for once, this is coincidental), and was originally meant for DEB, and RPM-over-APT and Phar bundles.

Since this is closely related to the original question, there are also tools to build Debian packages more easily. Somewhat outdated: [EPM](https://www.msweet.org/projects.php?Z2). Much more contempoary: [FPM](https://github.com/jordansissel/fpm/wiki). And my personal fork thereof: [XPM](http://fossil.include-once.org/xpm/) (more lazy approach for packaging scripting language apps.)

Comment: How do I add the gpg key when I want to use that repo?

Comment: Usually something like `wget …/public.gpg -O- | apt-key add -`

Comment: What would I need to change if I did want to support multiple architectures?

Comment: @starbeamrainbowlabs Not entirely sure, but I think `dpkg-scanpackages -m` might suffice. It'll list all architectures in the same Release file still. But as long as each .deb has a unique name / or is stored in distinct subdirs (amd64/, all/) it ought to work out. Else go for one of the more complex repository tools.

Answer (score 7):

Yes. You can do this. You just need to organize the files in the right way and create the index files. If you put the directory structure inside the document root of your web server the packages can just be accessed via the web server.

[Here](https://web.archive.org/web/20230503192430/https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/repository-howto/repository-howto) is a detailed description how the files need to be organized and how the index files are created.

You can also use a tool called [reprepro](http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/286) if you are willing to install that one package. This will make the administration a little more convenient.

Comment: @txwikinger: The reason I can't install packages is because the server is running centOS :)

Comment: Well. you don't need to. You can create everything on a different computer and just rsync the whole tree to the centos server

Comment: Yeah, I would definitely second the use of reprepro. It will make your life so much easier. Creating the repo on a different computer might even be a feature, in case it allows you to protect your signing key better.

Comment: @andol & @txwikinger: I'm trying but running into problems. Please see my updated question.

Comment: For your dists file you will still need ./binary-<specific arch>.

Comment: @andol: Sorry, my 'dists' file? I have a dists folder at the root of the repository.

Comment: Ok, that was probably a bit disambiguous from my side. Apart from it should have been plural. I am also used to separate the actual packages under ./pool while ./dists is reserved for meta data/package info. That is, you will need to have separate ./dists/stable/main/binary-{amd64,i386} containing their own Packages* files. Yet, it is possible to have them refer to the same actual .deb file. Hence (partly) the popular convention of the ./pool directory.

Comment: Does apache have the permissions to access the apt/dists folder as well the files inside?

Comment: I upped you for mentioning reprepro.  Trivial repositories should be considered anathema these days.  It's far easier to use reprepro and dput new packages to the repo.

Answer (score 2):

You can perhaps also consider a [Launchpad PPA](https://help.launchpad.net/Packaging/PPA)

Answer (score 0):

For anyone facing this error after following mario's answer:

```
Unable to find expected entry 'Packages' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)
```

do the following:

```
dpkg-scanpackages debs /dev/null > Packages
gzip -k Packages
apt-ftparchive release . > Release
gpg --default-key $KEYID -abs -o Release.gpg Release
```

I put my `*.deb` files in `debs` folder.