# How to make our own repository?

Tags: package-management, ppa, launchpad

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to set up an APT repository?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/529/how-to-set-up-an-apt-repository)

I want to create my own repository for my 'deb' applications that I had made.

What should I do or is any tutorial to create my own repository that can be integrated in package repository? (Included in file `/etc/apt/sources.list`)

Let's just say I already have my own domain name like www.myapps.com.
or is any solution to put my applications into launchpad?

note :

1. My application has been already in .deb (ready to be installed).
2. There is no source code (I just downloaded from the aplications site and recreate it into a 'deb' with dpkg -build *application-name*).