# The "Repository" howtos and standards

Tags: repository

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to set up an APT repository?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/529/how-to-set-up-an-apt-repository)

I'm obliged to maintain a daily-updated offline Ubuntu repository, that should be signed by my digital signature and be in a standard format.

I usually do `dpkg-scanpackages -m . > ./Packages` in my repo folder to create local repositories (and never sign anything!). Are there any standards to create and maintain a debian / ubuntu repository? I can see that almost all archive sites are in same format. They have different directories for .deb files and indexes. Also they have different architectures and distributions (`pool`, `dist`, ...)

I would like to know how to make a standard repository.