# How to create a repository for Ubuntu?

Tags: apt, package-management, repository, debian

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to set up an APT repository?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/529/how-to-set-up-an-apt-repository)

I hope I have more success here then I had anywhere else. I'd like to create a repository to host my software (ex. packages.linuxmint.com or moonOS linuxfreedom).

I have already tried a PPA. It is just not for me because it doesn't offer what I am looking for. I need a real repo.

How can I make a repository that will work with APT?
Also, I don't believe a "local" or "private" repo is what I'm looking for. I want it to be so that anyone can use it :)

Comment: You want to make a backup of all your **software** (as your downloaded soft) or what?

Comment: No Lucio, I am just wanting to upload my packages to this repository for people to use. And Jorge Castro that link doesn't work for me. He seemed to have already done something before asking and the links some macguy has posted is apparently obsolete.

Answer (score 2):

You need to do two things (I think). Firstly, create a local repository. The steps for doing this are already well documented (see https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Personal).

Then, place the folder structure for this repository in a public directory on a web server, make the folder structure public, and have users update their software sources or `/etc/apt/sources.list` file with an entry to point to the repository on your file server.