# How do I create a private ppa server?

Tags: ppa

I am in a research and a step of it is to create a ppa to add academic files. Due the very low speed internet and the impossibility of transforming ppas hosted in launchpad into public, it must be hosted in the local server. I have tried to follow a tutorial from 2009, but no success. Can someone help me on it?

Comment: Does it have to be a PPA server or is this a general idea? Is it the intention to add these PPAs to any system that is installed? If so would it not be easier to have that installation finish with a shell script that pulls those PPAs from a server and add the from within that script?

Comment: Yes it has to be. I could do it, but I want the ppa private. The idea is to give a key to the users that I want to give access and with it they could authenticate into the server. This would be the only way to have access.

Comment: the key would be added using a file, in the repository configurations.

Comment: It could be nice if you accept an answer (if it solve the problem)

Answer (score 11):

A ppa repository is simply (approximately) a APT repository that is managed by launchpad server.

As an alternative, if you don't want to set up a launchpad server (that isn't easy), you could simply make an apt repository, that is more easy and permit you to distribute your packages privately.

You can see other questions about that in [askubuntu - How to set up an apt repository](https://askubuntu.com/questions/529/how-to-set-up-an-apt-repository).

And from that question, you can follow this [guide on how to make a repository](http://www.isotton.com/software/debian/docs/repository-howto/repository-howto.html). See that you have two options, a simple (easy to follow but no so automatic for users) and an advanced (complex but easy to use for users).

Answer (score 2):

This is not going to be easy.

As far as I can tell the usage of PPA's is launchpad.net only. So there is no PPA server.

From: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+ppas

> Personal Package Archives (PPA) allow you to upload Ubuntu source packages to be built and published as an apt repository by Launchpad. You can find out more about PPAs and how to use them in our [help page](https://help.launchpad.net/Packaging/PPA).

So to answer your question: you will need to run your own Launchpad instance. [Lucky for your there is a very lengthy article on this here](https://dev.launchpad.net/Running).

From the link some important notes:

> Building and running Launchpad requires a computer running Ubuntu. The production Launchpad.net site runs on Ubuntu 10.04 LTS. Developers mostly run 10.04 LTS, 11.10 or 12.04 LTS, but others may work.
>
> The recommended development configuration is Ubuntu 12.04 LTS or later running Launchpad in an [LXC container](https://dev.launchpad.net/Running/LXC) to minimise its impact on the wider system.
>
> Note: the changes introduced by the install script may break your current web development setup, so it is advisable to try Launchpad in a virtual machine or an LXC container, as described above.

---

Also have a look at [Does anyone have experience with a private Launchpad instance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5420774/does-anyone-have-experience-with-a-private-launchpad-instance)

Comment: PPA's are a Debian thing, it is not specific to launchpad.