# How to setup an apt server

Tags: apt, updates

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to set up an APT repository?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/529/how-to-set-up-an-apt-repository)

At my place of work we have some commercial applications that we want to deploy to ubuntu machines internally and keep them up to date.

We are wondering if we can achieve this by settings up an internal apt server which will host the debian packages. And have our internal users access this similar to a PPA (this seems to be what google does with Chrome)

Is it possible to setup an internal apt server? And if so how do we do it?