# How to create command line application in eclipse (c++ or java)?

Tags: command-line

How to create command line application c++ or Java?
I have some commands which I would like to convert into an application.
How to do it in eclipse?
Just for example consider:

```
sudo apt-get upgrade xyz
```

I want to get it into ubuntu repository. 
Or I'll create a gui using qt with c++ or java plugin.

Comment: What do you mean by an "application"? If you have a command, it's already an application. Do you mean to ask how you package it up for distribution? How to get it into the Ubuntu repos?

Comment: I think he is trying to make a package that can be added to a PPA and updated/modified and upgraded via apt-get.  But in it's current form this question is too vague to answer...

Comment: Are you looking for ways to creating a command line application? Please be more specific about exactly what you want so we can satisfactorily answer your question.

Comment: This appears to be *two* questions: one asking how to make an application that runs commands, and another asking what the different options are for making programs available to Ubuntu users. If that is the case, I recommend removing the second question (by editing), changing the title to reflect just the first one, searching for answers to the second question, and posting the second question as a separate question if you don't find answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C++ you can use `int system (const char* command);` function.

Example:

```
/* system example : DIR */
#include <stdio.h>      /* printf */
#include <stdlib.h>     /* system, NULL, EXIT_FAILURE */

int main ()
{
  int i;
  printf ("Checking if processor is available...");
  if (system(NULL)) puts ("Ok");
    else exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
  printf ("Executing command DIR...\n");
  i=system ("dir");
  printf ("The value returned was: %d.\n",i);
  return 0;
}
```

Source: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/system/

In your case you can use:

```
system ("sudo apt-get upgrade");
```

In Java is slightly more complicated. You can use `exec` method of the Runtime class in java.lang. See http://www.linuxforums.org/forum/programming-scripting/65117-c-c-system-function-analog-java.html

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be able to use the `apt-get` command with your programm, it needs to be in a apt repository, whose url must be in the `/etc/apt/sources.list` file. You can learn how to set up your own apt repository [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/529/how-to-set-up-an-apt-repository).