# How to make apt-get known the imported deb package in apt-cacher

Tags: apt, package-management, apt-cacher

I compiled memcached with sasl enabled, and made a deb package: memcached_1.4.15-1_amd64.deb by checkinstall with package name: memcached-sasl-enabled. I imported it to apt-cacher repo by /usr/share/apt-cacher/apt-cacher-import.pl, then I ran apt-get update, apt-get install memcached-sasl-enabled, it says cannot found.

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Couldn't find package memcached-sasl-enabled
```

How can I make apt-get known it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Apt-cacher (and it's cousin Apt-cacher-NG) are just proxies to normal repositories. What you are looking for is a full-blown repository server. This answers have already methods how you can accomplish this:

https://askubuntu.com/a/89698/169736