# Can we push software to clients ?

Tags: wireless, networking

We need [HTcondor](http://research.cs.wisc.edu/htcondor/) to be installed on computers in network Which is our own campus network for throughput computing, we need maximum nodes so we can do it in a better way.

Mentioned network have many computers which are desktops, laptops some are connected to LAN and some connected through WLAN. There are 3 networks faculty, students, and senior students but for simplicity I am assuming its just single network. and they have different operating systems(Windows 7, Windows 8, Ubuntu, Windows XP) but I am assuming all have Ubuntu.

So how we can somehow broadcast it in network and install on all computers or prompt a pop up to user for installation ?

Or install it anyway on machines, I have looked and only thing i could find is [Microsoft Group Policy](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/314934) to install software remotely but this article applies to only Windows 2000 and its not cross platform either.

How can I do that on cross platform or at least on Ubuntu machines using Ubuntu ?

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1):

for ubuntu machines, you just need to setup an apt repository and add it to the software sources on all machines. then all the ubuntu users can install your software and get updated when you update your software in the apt repository.

> see [How to set up an APT repository?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/529/how-to-set-up-an-apt-repository) for more details.

alternatively, you can just use the [launchpad](https://launchpad.net/) PPA service.

> see https://help.launchpad.net/Packaging/PPA for more details on how to register a lauchpad account and publish your software through a PPA.

Comment: I want to push software in a campus network i dont want to set up APT repository or dont want to use PPA service. That will certainly kill the purpose.

Comment: if you want to publish software to clients, no matter how you to do it, you need to setup a server and there must be a mechanism for clients to discover it. i think an apt server is the simplest thing to publish software for ubuntu and this integrates well with ubuntu's package management system.

Comment: You are saying right. But i don't want clients to discover the software I want server to push it on all clients and all they have to do is accept the request. Is it possible ?