# Clients Not Working With Offline Ubuntu 16.04 Repository

Tags: server, apt, apt-mirror

I have followed the instructions to install a local repository for a segregated network.  I apt-mirror to a local drive, rsynce to and external, then 'sneakernet' to the segregated networ.  I can see the files when I go to http://inside-server/ubuntu.  I've also updated two clients to point to the inside-server for the xenial files.  One of these is the actual repo server.

The sources.list has:

```
deb http://inside-server/ubuntu xenial main restricted multiverse
```

I tried a few permutations of this line that I have found.  However, I always get this error:

```
# apt update
Ign:1 http://inside-server/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Err:2 http://inside-server/ubuntu xenial Release
  404  Not Found
Reading package lists... Done
E: The rpository 'http://inside-server/ubuntu xenial Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
#
```

I've spent three days googling and reading but the 'normal' directions all say my installation should just work.  I looked at creating a key.  That became involved and seemed out of the norm.  My segregated network is trusted, so I looked at allowing an unauthenticated repository on the client.  However, the man page for apt-secure points to apt.conf which is broken out in 16.04.  I haven't yet found a clear example on what to change.

So, I'm punting.  Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: If you read the error message it states you did not generate a release file. See https://askubuntu.com/questions/529/how-to-set-up-an-apt-repository

Comment: And if you read standard repository mirroring examples, you don't have to.  They are downloaded with the packages.

Answer (score 0):

Well, after taking a very conservative approach, I started hacking on the internal repo.  My problem was I had linked the wrong path to http://inside-server/ubuntu.

The apt-mirror command clones more that what is needed to host a mirror.  The actual path is /mirror/ubuntu.archive.com/ubuntu.

Comment: Could you clarify this a bit, maybe with a really ELI5 example?