# Can't install grive

Tags: package-management, ppa, grive

I'm trying to install grive, but i recieve the following error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package grive
```

I ran the usual commands:

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install grive
```

Ubuntu 17.10

Any ideas?

Comment: There is not a package listed there specifically for Ubuntu 17.10 (Artful Aardvark).  Possibly grive2?

Comment: I tried grive2, too. Problem remains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Temporarily) Fixed it by manually installing grive, following http://yourcmc.ru/wiki/Grive2#Installation.

Still looking forwards a long-term solution, because manual installation doesn't provide automatic updates.

Comment: Google Drive integration in GNOME 3.18 and newer: https://askubuntu.com/questions/161273/is-there-a-google-drive-client-available/320333#320333

Comment: @karel: Grive won't install from ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8 on Ubuntu 17.10

Answer (score 1):

It's simply [not a part of the official distribution](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=artful&section=all&arch=any&keywords=grive&searchon=names), and as the website itself doesn't point to a repository, but leads you through building it yourself, there just isn't any other way. At least until you [provide your own repo](https://askubuntu.com/questions/529/how-to-set-up-an-apt-repository) and keep it up-to-date.